# Pandas / Numpy way of finding difference between column headers and index headers

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a pandas dataFrame that look like this:

```
import pandas as pd

cols = [1,2,5,15]
rows = [1,0,4]
data = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros((len(rows),len(cols))))
data.columns = cols
data.index = rows

    1   2   5   15
1   0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
0   0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
4   0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
```

I want to find the difference between the column's headers and indexes/row headers, such that the absolute differences populate the table as such:

```
    1   2   5   15
1   0.0 1.0 4.0 14.0
0   1.0 2.0 5.0 15.0
4   3.0 2.0 1.0 11.0
```

Is their a Pandas or Numpy way of doing this? Here I'm using a small data set, in reality I have nearly 1000,000 rows and 100 columns. I'm looking for a quick and efficient way of making this computation. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach using [`NumPy broadcasting`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/user/basics.broadcasting.html) -

```
# Extract index and column as int arrays
indx = df.index.values.astype(int)
cols = df.columns.values.astype(int)

# Perform elementwise subtracttion between all elems of indx against all cols
a = np.abs(indx[:,None] - cols)
df_out = pd.DataFrame(a, df.index, df.columns)
```

Sample input, output -

```
In [43]: df
Out[43]: 
     1    2    5   15
1  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
4  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0

In [44]: df_out
Out[44]: 
   1  2  5  15
1  0  1  4  14
0  1  2  5  15
4  3  2  1  11
```

Alternatively, for in-situ edit in `df`, assign back with `df[:]` -

```
In [58]: df[:] = a

In [59]: df
Out[59]: 
   1  2  5  15
1  0  1  4  14
0  1  2  5  15
4  3  2  1  11
```

Also, if we do have access to the index and columns information, we can get `a` directly from them, like so -

```
a = np.abs(np.asarray(rows)[:,None] - cols)
```

**Further performance boost**

We can boost it further with [`numexpr` module](https://github.com/pydata/numexpr/wiki/Numexpr-Users-Guide) to perform those `absolute` computations for large datasets to get `a`, like so -

```
import numexpr as ne

def elementwise_abs_diff(rows, cols): # rows would be indx
    I = np.asarray(rows)[:,None]
    return ne.evaluate('abs(I - cols)')
```

This gives us `a`, which could be fed to create `df_out` shown earlier or assigned back to `df`.

Timings -

```
In [93]: rows = np.random.randint(0,9,(5000)).tolist()

In [94]: cols = np.random.randint(0,9,(5000)).tolist()

In [95]: %timeit np.abs(np.asarray(rows)[:,None] - cols)
10 loops, best of 3: 65.3 ms per loop

In [96]: %timeit elementwise_abs_diff(rows, cols)
10 loops, best of 3: 32 ms per loop
```

Comment: This works really well! I tried it using a matrix with 1000,000 columns and 600 rows and works in under 2 secs! Thanks

Comment: @user3063482 It should! It's NumPy and in it we are leveraging broadcasting :)

Comment: @user3063482 Check out the just added method with `numexpr` at the end too!

Comment: Thanks! This is very efficient